# Python: Writing Values to Table In MSSQL Server

Tags: python, sql, sql-server

I currently have a connection successfully established with a Database in MSSQL Server.

Below is my code (login credentials removed).

```
import pypyodbc

    connection = pypyodbc.connect('Driver={XXX};' 
                                  'Server=XXX;' 
                                  'Database=XXX;' 
                                  'uid=XXX;' 
                                  'pwd=XXX')

    cursor = connection.cursor()
```

Below is what I'm trying to insert into SQL table:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MODREPORT(rowid, location) VALUES (?,?)", (3, 'fleet'))
connection.commit

connection.close()
```

After running the execute code the following appears:

```
<bound method Connection.commit of <pypyodbc.Connection object at 0x0000000009CB88D0>>
```

BUT nothing is written into the SQL table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `connection.commit()` as a function, not just reference the bound method.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO MODREPORT(rowid, location) VALUES (?,?)", (3, 'fleet'))
connection.commit()
connection.close()
```

Comment: when I run the above code... the SQL side times out  before anything can be written... thoughts?

Comment: Which line times out?